# Convert from GPT to MBR and vice versa

Tags: powershell

I would like to use PowerShell to convert a disk from GPT to MBR and vice versa.

To convert to MBR, I've tried with:

```
Clear-Disk -Number 3 -Confirm:$false -RemoveData -RemoveOEM
Initialize-Disk -Number 3 -PartitionStyle MBR
```

But it doesn't work if the disk has already been initialized.

[image]

Comment: From the Help file on Initialize-Disk: The Initialize-Disk cmdlet initializes a Disk object with the RAW partition style to either the MBR or GPT partition styles.  The default partition style is GPT. Disks must be initialized before they can be formatted and used to store data. Clear-Disk does not set the partition style to RAW. HTH

Comment: @RetiredGeek, as per Clear-Disk [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/clear-disk): "Cleans a disk by removing all partition information and un-initializing it". Uninitialising a disk means removing the partition type (aka "Partition style"), which then shows as "RAW" in the disk's Powershell properties. However, the final sentence of your comment is actually accurate when applied to removable media, which is presumably OP's disk type, and thus the reason for OP's confusion. Unfortunately, I have no better source for my claim other than my own testing.

Answer (score 1):

`Clear-Disk` will remove the partition style and un-initialize the disk completely.  I tested the above scenario several times flipping between GPT and MBR.  I couldn't reproduce the error.  Only time I could recreate the problem was when the disk really was initialized.

I did do a quick test using `Set-Disk -Number 3 -PartitionStyle GPT` and back to MBR, this seemed to work so long as there were no partitions.  I was able to remove all partitions with: `Get-Partition -DiskNumber 3 | Remove-Partition -confirm:$false`.

Given your the error is unexplained as of yet, I can't say this approach will work.

Comment: `Clear-Disk` does un-initialize virtual hard disks and may also un-initialize physical hard disks (not tested), but it does not un-initialize a physical USB drive. Maybe you can reproduce the error with a USB drive.